# How can I RDP to a (Azure) VM while using a VPN service on the VM itself?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, remote-desktop, azure

I have an RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) connection to an Azure VM running Windows 10 from my own Windows 10 machine. I need to use a VPN service (such as TunnelBear) on my Azure VM to change my IP for a certain application. However, when I change my IP on TunnelBear (VPN service), I instantly lose connection to the VM on my RDP connection.

My question is, how would I change my IP using a VPN service on an Azure VM without losing the RDP connection?

Comment: Check out this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/193308/vpn-within-a-remote-desktop-session

Comment: @f01 Yes, I think this answers my question, thanks!